# How to use a default value for a constructor argument?

Tags: ruby, constructor

I am trying to figure out how to make my class constructor allow for the user to pass in a value for a variable, or just to let the class do it.

My class is `Graph` has an instance variable `@nodes`. I want to call either `Graph.new()` assigning `@nodes = []`, or `Graph.new(list_of_nodes)` assigning `@nodes = list_of_nodes`.

Is this possible, or should I just make two separate constructors?

Answer (score 3):

You can't write two separate constructors - there is no function overloading in ruby (because it is not needed). You can set the default for the param:

```
class Graph

  def initialize(list_of_nodes = [])
    @nodes = list_of_nodes
  end

  def nodes
    @nodes
  end

end

Graph.new.nodes          #=> []
Graph.new([:node]).nodes #=> [:node]
```

Answer (score 2):

A more Ruby-idiomatic version of BroiSatse's answer:

```
class Graph
  attr_reader :nodes

  def initialize (*nodes)
    @nodes = nodes
  end
end

Graph.new.nodes # => []
Graph.new(:node1, :node2).nodes # => [:node1, :node2]
```

`attr_reader :nodes` is the more idiomatic equivalent of `def nodes() @nodes end`.

Using the "rest arg" `*nodes`, `[]` will be assigned to `@nodes` when no arguments are given. It also allows you to leave out the brackets from the argument list.